# How does Sonic know what Wi-Fi and the Internet are?

Tags: disney, wreck-it-ralph, sonic-the-hedgehog, ralph-breaks-the-internet

When the Wi-Fi router is plugged into the Game Central Station near the beginning of *Ralph Breaks the Internet*, this scene occurs:

> **RALPH:** "Whiffey"? Or "Wifey"? Well, it’s either whiffleball or an arranged marriage game.
>
> **SONIC:** It's actually pronounced "Wi-Fi", Ralph.
>
> **RALPH:** Yeah, that's what I said.
>
> **SONIC:** And Wi-Fi is the Internet, which is an online community where human beings go to shop and play games and socialize.

It is quickly made very clear that none of the other video game characters know what the Internet is, whereas Sonic *does*; and I am confused as to how. Now, one might respond that the information was added to Sonic's code (or something), but the original *Sonic the Hedgehog* game was released in 1991, and the Internet, at least as we know it today (as the place for social media and other things), didn't exist back then.

Answer (score 5):

In the [official novelisation](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/Wreck-It_Ralph:_The_Junior_Novelization) the exchange is very slightly different. Sonic explains that he's *heard* (from someone) about Wi-Fi and the Internet. It's not explained who imparted this knowledge but at least we know that it's second-hand info.

> “And Wi-Fi is the Internet,” continued the kind hedgehog. **“Which I’ve heard** is an online community where human beings go to shop and play games and socialize. It’s said to be a wondrous, miraculous place.”

As we see later in the film, the game characters are perfectly well able to see and hear what the humans are talking about, so it's likely that he just overheard someone in the arcade mention it.

> “Good luck,” Mr. Litwak said. “That’ll be like finding a needle in a—”
>
> “I found one,” said Swati cheerfully. “See, eBay has a wheel, Mr. Litwak.” Swati held her phone up to show him.
>
> “Really? Great,” he said.
>
> “See?” said Ralph inside the game. “Those kids have it under control.”